# Performance of Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm interested in evaluating the performance of using Cloud Functions for Firebase, so I've set up a simple function with basically the same code as [this example from Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js). What the function does is that is simply listens for new messages at a certain node in Firebase, and then sends a push notification to the receiver of that message.

Next, I wrote a script that bombards the messages node by adding x new children there every second. I found out that the function seems to be able to handle up to about 40 new messages per second, anything more than that and the notifications start to lag more and more behind. This seems like pretty poor performance – too poor for us to use in production – and I wonder what the bottleneck might be here. Of course, Functions are still in beta, but according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas), each function should be able to run 400 concurrent invocations.

Comment: It looks like you're not asking a programming question here, but instead looking for conversation.  I'd suggest instead posting to firebase-talk Google group or joining the Slack channel.  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: I could phrase my question like this: what are the performance bottlenecks when using Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Comment: That's really not a specific coding question as outlined in the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, it's an excellent question for the google groups community.

Comment: Here we go: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/xjA5bB26XG0